# How to watch a Rails object in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to watch a Rails object in the console?

I can of course keep manually repeating a command and checking for changes, but it would be nice to be able to do something like `watch Booking.find_by_id(39)` and be notified of the changes.

To give a bit of context I've got a DelayedJob in heroku which I want to monitor the progress of.

It would be nice also to be able to watch objects in the console while performing actions on them in the web app.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that for the specific problem you're talking about, which sounds like progress-monitoring of a DelayedJob, there is a gem available to do that for you.  But as a more general answer to your question... you're using a programming language, so make use of it! :)

```
def watch(&block)
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      puts block.call.inspect
      sleep 2
    end
  end
end

watch { Booking.find_by_id(39) }
```

Comment: :-) You probably also want to capture the return value of `#watch` into a variable (say, `t`) so that you can later type `t.kill` when you're sick of your irb session being swamped with background thread output.

Comment: It would be nice to find a way to only dump output if the value changes so that the signal to noise ration is more favorable, but overall I like this answer.

Comment: I'm sure you can modify a line or two in my code to do that. If not, I'll post that solution for you.  Hint: you are receiving the thing your displaying each time, and you are inside a loop ;)

Comment: Is this exclusive to 1.9? I'm on 1.8 and it doesn't seem to behave as expected... Also what was the gem you were referring to?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't behave as expected?  It wasn't really supposed to be a complete example.  For a start it will run in the background, with all the output appearing in the IRB console.  You'll want to `#join` the Thread it creates in order to avoid that behaviour.  It should work under 1.8 and 1.9. The gem was purely hypothetical... just guessing that one exists (it does for Resque, but I don't use DelayedJob).

Comment: That said, if you add `#join`, you might as well just remove the Thread entirely since it will become a blocking call anyway.